# How effective is using local property to test Shannon capacity?

Tags: graph-theory, it.information-theory

A key tool in graph theory is the laplacian which is a local property. We can form a semidefinite programming and get an upper bound for Shannon capacity using laplacian.

Shannon capacity is inherently a global measure on independence sets.

Why does using a local property such as laplacian helps give capacity upper bound?

If we have a more global property would our estimates improve and what choices we have for such global properties?